# How to add custom bias/offset in modeling neural network through neuralnet in R?

Tags: r, keras, neural-network

I have a code for a neural network model which uses `keras`.

```
features <- layer_input ( shape=c(ncol(feature_matrix)))
net <- features %>%
  layer_dense(units=q,activation='tanh') %>%
  layer_dense(units=1,activation=k_exp)
volumes <- layer_input(shape=c(1))
offset <- volumes %>%
  layer_dense(units=1,activation='linear',use_bias=FALSE,trainable=FALSE,
              weights=list(array(1,dim=c(1,1))))
merged <- list(net,offset) %>%
  layer_multiply()
model <- keras_model(inputs=list(features,volumes),outputs=merged)
model %>% compile(loss='mse',optimizer='rmsprop')

fit <- model %>% fit(list(feature_matrix,offset_matrix),response_matrix,epochs=100,
                     batch_size=10000,validation_split=0.1)
```

However, I cannot find a way to display the network architecture with keras. I want to redefine my neural network using the `neuralnet` package instead.

I just encountered `neuralnet` and am clueless on **where I should insert the custom bias/offset that I have**.

Its usage is given by

```
neuralnet(formula, data, hidden = 1, threshold = 0.01,
  stepmax = 1e+05, rep = 1, startweights = NULL,
  learningrate.limit = NULL, learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5,
  plus = 1.2), learningrate = NULL, lifesign = "none",
  lifesign.step = 1000, algorithm = "rprop+", err.fct = "sse",
  act.fct = "logistic", linear.output = TRUE, exclude = NULL,
  constant.weights = NULL, likelihood = FALSE)
```

How do I do that?